# Android Image view and list view in scroll view

Tags: android

I have one image view and list view in my XML file.
Functionality Required: When I scroll list view then image view should also scroll with slow scrolling speed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parallax view inside a list-view instead of using image-view.

Answer (score 0):

It's called **Parallax Effect**.

You can use [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1577)

Answer (score 0):

Use the android-design library wich already integrates the parallax effect. You can take a look at Chris Banes [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) example to show how to do it.